# Passing a condition as a parameter to an iterator

Tags: java, eclipse, parameter-passing

I'm almost finished with my project, although there is one thing that I can't get past.

Let me quote it first:

> The class Board must also oer a method that returns an iterator that will
>   return all the elements on the board (not including items carried by robots) that
>   satisfy a given condition. Examples of conditions are all elements that have an
>   energy of at least 1000 Ws (the iterator will then not return walls nor surprise
>   boxes, because they have no known energy), all elements in some sub range of
>   the board, all items on the board, etc.

So, I have a board with elements on. (Robots, certain items, walls, ...)

In class we have seen how to implement Iterable, and override the method iterator() if needed, but now I need to pass conditions as a parameters to this iterator?

My best shot was this method in class Board:

```
    public Iterator<Element> getAllElementsByCondition(boolean condition) {
    HashSet<Element> result = new HashSet<Element>();
    for (Element element : elements)
        if (Board.this.hasElement(element) && condition)
            result.add(element);
    return result.iterator();
}
```

However, as you see, I have no idea how to pass the condition as a parameter to the method.

I also don't really know if this is how I create the iterator.

EDIT: 
I'm not allowed to use any external libraries

Comment: You just need through list of elements from board using iterator and check condition manually (by code)

Comment: The point is that I don't know what condition the user will ask for.

Comment: Take a look at guava `Iterators` or `Iterables` (http://code.google.com/searchframe#UKMs0lhE9bg/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.java) filtering methods

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any external libraries :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are not allowed to use an external library like Guava, you could:

1. create a `Filter<T>` interface, that has one method, let's call it `boolean match(T obj)`.
2. pass a `Filter<Element>` to your iterator, that implements the `match` method to test for the condition, for example `return "The name I'm looking for".equals(element.getName());`.
3. test in your loop if `filter.match(element)` then `result.add(element)`.

**EDIT**
Your new method would then be:

```
public Iterator<Element> getAllElementsByCondition(Filter<Element> filter) {
```

And you would call it this way:

```
Iterator<Element> it = getAllElementsByCondition(new Filter<Element> () {
    public boolean match(element candidate) {
        return /* Enter your condition here */;
    }
});
```

the condition could be for example:

```
candidate.getEnergy() > 1000
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, but I don't understand it completely...

I'm with you on the interface part. But then, step 2, could you clarify it a bit?

Comment: @AdFundum See my edit. You could even call the `Filter` interface `Condition`. And you could replace match by `satisfiedBy` for example. That way you stick to your high level goal language.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Guava's collections augmentations.  In this case, specifically [`Collections2.filter()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#filter%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) or [`Collections2.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v12.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform%28java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29).  If you do this, you can supply a `Predicate` describing the condition you care about, and just use `filter()` to run through the collection and return a collection of matching elements.  Here's a very localized example:

```
public Iterator<Element> getAllElementsByCondition(Predicate<Element> condition) {
  return Collections2.filter(elements, condition).iterator(); 
}
```

But not that you may change the structure more drastically if you embrace the [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) way of doing things.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any external libraries :(

Comment: Hmm.  Where does that constraint come from?  In any case, @assylias probably has the next best thing.  Reimplement something like what Guava provides.  Can't tell from your question how much flexibility you need.  Are you asking how to implement an `Iterator`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should clarify the task. I imagine that your method should work, though it should be narrowed to something like `getAllElementsWithEnergyGreaterThan(int minEnergy)`. And in your loop you compare your energy with minEnergy.

Comment: I think my assigners should clarify the task too, but sadly, they do not :/